# How to disable horizontal scroll and shrink the size of elements on mobile view?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I am using **Material-ui** for my project. Right now I have a lot of anchor elements displaying like a table within a `Paper` component from mui. Because this table is very long, it generates a horizontal scroll bar in the mobile view which is not what I want. I'm wondering is there a way to shrink the width of all my table-like anchor elements so that the horizontal scroll bar won't appear? (I don't want to use `overflow-x: hidden` to hide the elements)

A simplified version of my code:

```
class Row extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const cell = (<a class="linkCell" key={cell.id} href="#"></a>);
      const row = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      row.push(cell);
    }
    return <div>{Row}</div>
  }
}

class WholeTable extends React.Component {
    render() {
  const row = <Row key={row.id}/>
  const table = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    table.push(row);
  }
  return <Paper>{table}</Paper>
    };
}
```

What it looks like now (before and after horizontal scrolling): 
[image: before scrolling horizontally]

[image: after scrolling horizontally]

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS file, you could simply use

```
width: 100vw;
```

in all your elements, to shrink them to 100% the width of your viewport. However you'll have to be careful that if you use any padding, you'll have to subtract those pixels from the width.